# Django, get scheme (http or https), pre request.scheme implementation

Tags: django

How can I get the scheme (http or https) from a Django request object? I'm using Django 1.5, which is before request.scheme was introduced.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the scheme by calling [`request.scheme`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme) in the view:

```
def view(request):
    scheme = request.scheme
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can also check the return value of [`.is_secure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure) method:

```
def view(request):
    scheme = request.is_secure() and "https" or "http"
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use [`.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) to get the absolute URI of the request and parse it using `.urlsplit()` to retrieve the scheme:

```
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import urlsplit

def view(request):
    scheme = urlsplit(request.build_absolute_uri(None)).scheme
    ...
```

Comment: You could also use: 'request.scheme', which delivers either HTTP or HTTPS